# Set email notifications for the receivers of an envelope I have sent

Tags: docusignapi

I'm using the eSignature API the following way: I impersonate a user and I then send envelopes to other Docusign users from the same account. Now some of them want not to receive emails once the envelope has been completed. I know they could change it by themselves using the website, but can I do it on an envelope basis?
I read this article: https://www.docusign.com/blog/developers/common-api-tasks-change-email-notifications-programmatically but I am not sure if I need further consent from those users, or if I'm fine by only knowing their account ID and the user ID.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to impersonate them and make API calls as them, then they will need to grant consent to your application. If you have an organisation with a claimed domain, you can also grant consent [administratively](https://developers.docusign.com/platform/auth/consent/obtaining-admin-consent-internal/)

Comment: I don't wany to impersonate anybody else if it is not necessary. My app only has one user sending envelopes to the other users

Comment: You'd need to impersonate them to modify their email permissions

Answer (score 0):

All you need is the userId and then follow the code in the ancile.
The userId you should already know, since you said you're impersonating that user (using JWT).

The C# code is this, but you need to find the userId to put in it:

```
var apiClient = new ApiClient(basePath);
// You will need to obtain an access token using your chosen authentication method
apiClient.Configuration.DefaultHeader.Add("Authorization", "Bearer " + accessToken);
UsersApi usersApi = new UsersApi(apiClient);
UserSettingsInformation userSettingsInformation = new UserSettingsInformation();
userSettingsInformation.SenderEmailNotifications = new SenderEmailNotifications();
userSettingsInformation.SenderEmailNotifications.EnvelopeComplete = "false";
usersApi.UpdateSettings(accountId, userId, userSettingsInformation);
```